# Are the domain layer, persistence layer and presentation layer things i need to memorize if i plan to learn MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I am watching some tutorials that go over some of the basics of C#. The guy teaching them is setting up the projects using a domain layer, a persistence layer, a presentation layer, and is using web forms. In the past i had taken a class on PHP with MVC but it has been a while. I don't remember anything about the way he is setting these projects up. Is this set ups something specific to web forms or C#? Is it something i need to know moving forward if i plan to work with the MVC model?

EDIT: Is this pattern used in MVC?

Comment: It's a design principle. If you are just starting to learn C# in general it might be better to get some syntax and library knowledge first. Although design principles are important, it will be hard to memorize if you're still struggling with a language in general. It is, btw, not bound to the technique. These principles are also valid in other languages.

Comment: I wouldn't say "memorize", but these are certainly concepts you should seek to *understand* if you want to write robust and reusable code.  (Note: These concepts have nothing to do with ASP.NET or any other specific language or tool.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've found a good tutorial.

The average MVC tutorial puts everything in one project, puts the business logic in controller methods and skips using domain models altogether. Then again, the average MVC tutorial doesn't reach beyond a simple "Hello World" or "TODO App".

Relevant search terms about these constructs, which should be explained in the tutorial (if not, find another one), are ["layered design"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture), with implementations such as N-tier and N-layer. If you search on that, you'll find plenty of resources explaining what it entails and why you should use it.

See for example [Martin Fowler's arcicle on PresentationDomainDataLayering](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PresentationDomainDataLayering.html).

It's definitely not necessary for learning WebForms or MVC, but it helps building scalable, testable, reusable application components.

Answer (score 0):

These are part of SOLID Principles and Separation of concern. They are a methodology that can be applied to pretty much all Languages and are good principles to follow.

Comment: You can have SOLID without layers and layers without SOLID, I wouldn't say they're that strongly related.